# SilverStripe 3.1 ListboxField save array to database

Tags: silverstripe

I want to know how to correctly save values selected with a ListboxField.

```
new ListboxField(
    $name = "Categorie",
    $title = "Catégorie(s)",
    Categories::get()->map('ID','Title'),
    $value = 1,
    $size = 4,
    $multiple = true
);
```

In my example, I can save more than one category to a `$db` field. I am using:

```
private static $db = array(
    'Categorie' => 'Varchar'
);
```

It works, but when I'm trying to get back categories names into a template it dosen't work at all. The data stored for example is `"1,4,9"`.

Is there a better way to store variables from ListboxField?

Comment: You need to set up your categories as a relation (probably a many_many relationship). This article may help explain: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/model/relations/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3dgoo is correct that you're probably best using a has_many or many_many relationship here. If for some reason you need to use a single text field, you would just need to manually add a method to your model to look up those related records:

```
public function getCategories() {
    if (empty($this->Categorie)) return null;
    return Categories::get()->filter('ID', explode(',', $this->Categorie));
}
```

You can then do something like the following in your template:

```
<% loop $Categories %><li>$Title</li><% end_loop %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `$many_many` relationship instead of a `$db` variable to manage your relationship between your object and `Categories`.

```
private static $many_many = array(
    'Categories' => 'Categories'
);

public function getCMSFields() {

    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', ListboxField::create(
        'Categories',
        'Catégories',
        Categories::get()->map('ID', 'Title')->toArray(),
        1,
        4,
        true
    ));

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Your answer seem to be logic, but for a reason, it doesnt work with Memberprofile module [link](https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-memberprofiles). I'm trying to extend Member with many_many categories and the CMS return me Internal server error.